# AS3. How to use public variable in timeline frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, actionscript, public, timeline

I'm creating game, in main class I have declared variable: `public var attack:Number = 0;` this is dynamic value (always changing) and I need  set It to 0 in last animation frame in timeline.

When I try to use `attack=0` in last frame I got error: `1120: Access of undefined property attack.`

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use events:

on your last frame:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("lastFrameCustomHandler", true, true));
```

on your code:

```
addEventListener("lastFrameCustomHandler", handleLastFrame); 
function handleLastFrame (event:Event):void 
{
  attack = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `addFrameScript` from your main class:

```
asset.addFrameScript( asset.totalFrames-1, function():void { attack = 0; } );
```

Elaborating a bit on how `addFrameScript()` works, whenever you compile a `MovieClip` from your library, if you did not associate a class with it, the compiler creates one for you behind the scenes. `addFrameScript()` is the undocumented bond between a MovieClips timeline and the script associated. When you run an `addFrameScript()` on a `MovieClip` you set it with the parameters `( frameNumber - 1, functionToCall )`. Your MovieClip timeline starts at frame 1, but this is really read as frame 0 when referencing (similar to that of how storage containers work starting at index 0).

In my example I passed what's known as an anonymous function. I created a function for the function parameter in `addFrameScript()` that will set the variable attack to 0 when we reach the specified frame. Of course you don't have to do it that way. Say you had a function:

```
function setAttackToZero():void {
    attack = 0;
}
```

You could just as easily pass that into the addFrameScript parameter:

```
asset.addFrameScript( asset.totalFrames-1, setAttackToZero );
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you explain me how this works? I go errors `1120: Access undefined of property asset and frameNumber `

Comment: Yes you need to replace asset when the name of your display object that has the animation timeline. then replace the frame number with the last frame number of your asset ( subtracted by 1 ). I assumed that information was given so I'll update the frameNumber part of the answer to be more specific.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? If asset's currentFrame != totalFrames It set attack = 0 or how It works?

Comment: Sure I can add how addFrameScript works into my answer. Although it should have been more like if currentFrame == totalFrames, not !=.